# R Programming: What does "[[k]][1:nrow(my_data)]" do within my modeling function? Looking for Greater Understanding of R Code

Tags: r, vector, syntax, brackets

I am running a classification model using R programming language.  I'm confused about what the following code in between ** ** means:

```
> for (a in 1:aparm){
+     predict<- round(fitted(model)**[[a]][1:nrow(data)]**)
+     
+     print (predict)
+     hello[a]<- sum(predict == my_data[,44]) / nrow(data)
+ }
```

Specifically: What is `[[a]][1:nrow(data)]` doing in the context of my function.  What does [[]] in the code mean within R?

Comment: `[` indexes 1 or more elements; `[[` indexes 1 element (and unlists it, if needed). `:` is the sequence operator. Are you learning machine learning and R at the same time?

Comment: I have experience with machine learning in Python; But this is my first exposure to R

Comment: Specifically if k=10 then in the context of my code what is [[10]][1:nrow(my_data)] doing?

Comment: `list(1:3, 11:19, 32:33)[[2]][3:5]` should demo all three operators to see what they do *in general*. I don't know what `kknn_model_cv` looks like so can't really help there.

Comment: Ah Very Helpful!  thank you

Comment: In addition, type `?"["` into your console to open the help page of the bracket function.

Answer (score 1):

- `fitted(model)` is apparently a list of vectors.
- `fitted(model)[[a]]` is a-th element of this list, which is a vector
- `fitted(model)[[a]][1:nrow(data)]` is first `nrow(data)` elements of this vector
- `nrow(data)` is number of rows in data, while `data` is dataframe or matrix.